# Django template - dynamic variable name

Tags: django

Good Afternoon,

How can I use a variable variable name in Django templates?

I have a custom auth system using `context`, `has_perm` checks to see if the user has access to the specified section.

`deptauth` is a variable with a restriction group name i.e SectionAdmin. I think `has.perm` is actually checking for `'deptauth'` instead of the variable value `SectionAdmin` as I would like.

```
{%if has_perm.deptauth %}
```

How can I do that? `has_perm.{{depauth}}` or something along those lines?

EDIT - Updated code

```
{% with arg_value="authval" %}
{% lookup has_perm "admintest" %}
{% endwith %}

{%if has_perm.authval %}
window.location = './portal/tickets/admin/add/{{dept}}/'+val;   
{% else %}
window.location = './portal/tickets/add/{{dept}}/'+val; 
{%endif%}
```

has_perm isn't an object.. it's in my context processor (permchecker):

```
class permchecker(object):

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request
    pass

def __getitem__(self, perm_name):
    return check_perm(self.request, perm_name)
```

Comment: `has_perm` is this your custom template tag?

Comment: `has_perm` cannot be a custom template tag. The template tag is `if`.

Answer (score 4):

You're best off writing your own [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for that. It's not difficult to do, and normal for this kind of situation.

I have not tested this, but something along these lines should work. Remember to handle errors properly!

```
def lookup(object, property):
    return getattr(object, property)()

register.simple_tag(lookup)
```

If you're trying to get a property rather than execute a method, remove those `()`.

and use it:

```
{% lookup has_perm "depauth" %}
```

Note that `has_perm` is a variable, and `"depauth"` is a string value. this will pass the string for lookup, i.e. get `has_perm.depauth`.

You can call it with a variable:

```
{% with arg_value="depauth_other_value" %}
    {% lookup has_perm arg_value %}
{% endwith %}
```

which means that the value of the variable will be used to look it up, i.e. `has_perm.depauth_other_value`'.

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately, Django templates are not great for the kind of finer distinction that you're trying to make here.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error:  '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'admintest'. Looks like it's treating admintest as a property instead of a lookup string

Comment: What exactly is `admintest`? Is it a dictionary? Show the code you are using to call the template tag.

Comment: Hi, admintest is just a string.   has_perm takes this string and checks the DB to see if the user has access to the group this string represents

Comment: {% with arg_value="authval" %}
    {% lookup has_perm "admintest" %}
{% endwith %}                                                                                                                                       {%if has_perm.authval %}
                window.location = './portal/tickets/admin/add/{{dept}}/'+val; 
            {% else %}
                window.location = './portal/tickets/add/{{dept}}/'+val; 
            {%endif%}

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
{{ dict|key:key_name }}
```

Filter:

```
def key(d, key_name):
    return d[key_name]
key = register.filter('key', key)
```

More information, [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371)

Comment: This only works for a dictionary, not attributes of an object.