# Constructing a variable name from strings

Tags: django, django-templates

Let's say I have two variables passed to a template: `var_a` and `var_b`. Is there a way to address them dynamically, or in other words construct the variable name from strings? Something like PHP's `$$var_name`.

For example if i have a `letter` variable with holds the value **`a`** or **`b`**, I'd like to render `var_a` by writing something like:

```
{{"var_"|some_sort_of_concat:letter}}
```

and get the value of `var_a` or `var_b` depending on the value of `letter`. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: The answer you've linked to says nothing about Django

Comment: Voting for reopen. This is not something that can be done with a templatefilter btw, you could do it with a templatetag though.

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148544/django-template-dynamic-variable-name

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with your variable names as keys and their values as values, then create a template filter to get the dictionary value by the given variable name. The variable name can also be a variable taken from a list or anything else:

```
d = {"var_a": "a", "var_b": "b"}
```

Send `d` to the template and create a template filter "`get_dictionary_value`":

```
def get_dictionary_value(d, key):
    try:
       if (key in d):
           return d[key]
    except:
        pass
    return ""
```

And then in the template:

```
{{ d|get_dictionary_value:"var_a" }}
```

Or:

```
{% for key in l %}
    {{ d|get_dictionary_value:key }}
{% endfor %}
```

By the way, the value of d[key] can also be a dictionary and you can apply this filter again (and again...):

```
{{ d|get_dictionary_value:key1|get_dictionary_value:key2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that if you're making decisions based on something that was already known, that computation should have happened before you rendered the template.

You could also use a dict i.e. var = {"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}
You can't index dicts directly in the template so depending on what you are trying to achieve either iterate over the dict or use a template filter like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067006/accessing-a-dict-by-variable-in-django-templates), [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371) is the link to the ticket.