# Django language for dynamic fields

Tags: html, django

```
<table class="table">       
    <tr>
        {% for item in summary.titles %}
            <th>{{ item }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for title in summary.titles %}
            <td> {{ summary.data[title] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to get data in a similar way?

> Exception Value:
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '[title]' from
>   'summary.data[title]'

```
var summary = {
    data:{
        title1: 1,
        title2:2
    }, 
    titles: [title1, title2]
}
```

Comment: Too less context to answer this. What data are you sending to this template? can you show any example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Django template - dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148544/django-template-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: @ArpitSolanki i try to add data

Comment: If you directly use `{{ title }}` It would work Why are you using array/getattr style

Comment: Have you tried this: `{% for title in summary.titles %}<td>{{ data.title }}</td>{% endfor %}` ??