# How to evaluate the concatenation of 2 variables in a template?

Tags: python, django, templates, variables

I'm trying to evaluate the concatenation of 2 variable in my django template

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ProductId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ProductName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ProductBrand = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def myfunction(request):
        headers = []
        id_update = request.GET.get('id')
        product = Product.objects.get(ProductId=id_update)
        table = Product._meta.get_fields()
        for field in Product._meta.fields:
            headers.append(field.name)
        template = "courses/gototemplate.html"
        return render(request, template, {'headers': headers, 'product':product})
```

gototemplate.html

```
{% extends "subfolder/base.html" %}
{% block page-header %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for header in headers %}
  <label for="name">{{ header }}</label>
  <input type="text"  name="prod{{productId}}" value="{{ {{product}}.{{header}} }}"></br>
</br>
{% endfor %}
```

The idea is to get the value of product for each product column table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template - dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148544/django-template-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 0):

Do you can this: `value="{{product}}.{{header}}"`

Comment: The above is a very poor comment - this answer clearly *does* at least attempt to provide an answer (and is identical to my own answer). I admit the grammar is a little confusing but the intention is clear: "do you can this" is supposed to be "you can do this".

Comment: This solution doesn't answer to my question. Let's imagine this in my database:
ProductId = 1
ProductName = "Aventador"
ProductBrand = "Lamborghini"

in the template: {{product}}.{{header}} displays Aventador.ProductId then Aventador.ProductName and Aventador.ProductBrand
instead of displaying 1 then Aventador and Lamborghini as I can do it with a simple print(product.ProductId) in my views.py

Answer (score 0):

```
{{product|add:header}}
```

or just

```
value="{{product}}.{{header}}"
```

You might be want to do variable in variable, please clarify in your question.